# Calculating NRI and IDI using a library-Reclassification

Tags: metrics

I tried to calculate NRI (Net reclassification index) and IDI using reclassification library.

I tried the following code after installing the library "reclassification": import nri from nri_f . but its showing error like nri is not found.